# Creating a package for laser_assembler

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the laser_assembler node. I am using tutorial on How to assemble laser scan lines into a composite point cloud. I saw one help also. But i dont knw hw to create a rospackage for it. Please help me. I am new to ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103416/creating-a-package-for-laser_assembler/) by [SAM MATHEW](https://answers.ros.org/users/9041/sam-mathew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The proper tutorial on creating packages is [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage). Select the proper button for rosbuild (old) or catkin (new).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1